# Edit runscript of singularity .sif container after building

Tags: containers, hpc

I have build a singularity container and uploaded it to my HPC service.

Is there a way to change the runscript of the .sif file without rebuilding the whole container? I have a shell on the service.

From my understanding of singularity this should be possible but I cant find out how.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a new sif, based on the old sif and add the new runscript.

```
Bootstrap: localimage
From: my-old.sif
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

You can convert a SIF file to a (writable) sandbox which is indeed a directory:

`sudo singularity build --sandbox <SANDBOX> <CONTAINER>.sif`

Then you can "get into" the sandbox and modify things there (note the `--writable` flag and the need for `sudo`):

`sudo singularity shell --writable <SANDBOX>`

Or you can edit `<SANDBOX>/singularity` or `<SANDBOX>/environment` as suggested by Quentin.

Additional goodies can be found in the `<SANDBOX>/.singularity.d` directory. Such as the `Singularity` file which is the recipe the container was built from.

Once you are happy with the changes you can convert the sandbox back to a (new) SIF file:

`sudo singularity build <NEW_CONTAINER>.sif <SANDBOX>`

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the file `<YOUR_CONTAINER.sif>/singularity` as it contains the runscript.

The same can be done for the environment with the file `<YOUR_CONTAINER.sif>/environment`.

Comment: How can I edit files inside a sif container?

Comment: The .sif container is just a folder. You can `cd <YOUR_CONTAINER.sif>` and then use a text editor like nano to edit the file: `nano singularity`.
I used the command `sudo singularity build --sandbox <YOUR_CONTAINER.sif> <YOUR_CONTAINER.def>` to get the container. I think that is why the container is like a directory.

Comment: My container was build without `--sandbox` so it is a file not a folder.